# How to random get a position corresponding to x,y,z?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a coordinate array

```
A_coor=(array([66, 67, 70, ..., 133, 133, 133]), 
        array([35, 35, 35, ..., 59,  59,  59]), 
        array([102,103,104, ...,105, 106, 107]))
```

I want to randomly pickup `k=2` positions in the array such that maintaining the coordinate. For example, if the second position is selected, the output should be `(67,35,103)`.

I am using below function but it does not maintain the position

```
import numpy as np
A_coor=(([66, 67, 70, 133, 133, 133]), 
        ([35, 35, 35, 59,  59,  59]), 
        ([102,103,104,105, 106, 107]))
k=2
x = np.random.choice (A_coor[0], size=k)
y = np.random.choice (A_coor[1], size=k)
z = np.random.choice (A_coor[2], size=k)
print (x,y,z)
```

The output is

```
[ 70 133] [35 35] [105 107]
```

You can see that (70,35,105) does not match with any postion in array

Comment: So you have a tuple of arrays right now?

Comment: Why don't you write A_coor as a 3xn matrix? Then you need to pick 10 random columns in range (n). In any case to get the second columns the index should be 1 not 2.

Comment: @all: I have update the question and clear to show the problem. Let check it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your overall tuple into an array, and then use slicing to get the coordinates.

```
import numpy as np

A_coor=(np.array([66, 67, 70, 133, 133, 133]), 
        np.array([35, 35, 35, 59,  59,  59]), 
        np.array([102,103,104, 105, 106, 107]))

column = np.random.choice(len(A_coor[0])) # Pick a random column index

coords = np.array(A_coor)[:, column]
print(column, coords)
```

If you want to do this for multiple columns, e.g. 10, then you can use a list comprehension. I don't think there's a native numpy approach to do this.

```
A_coor = np.array(A_coor)
columns = np.random.choice(np.arange(len(A_coor[0])), 
                           10, replace=True)

output = [A_coor[:, column] for column in columns]
```

Comment: Good solution. But please update to select `k` elements then I will accept your answer

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np 

A_corr=(np.array([66, 67, 70, 133, 133, 133]), 
        np.array([35, 35, 35, 59,  59,  59]), 
        np.array([102,103,104, 105, 106, 107]))

# convert to a more useful data structure
A_corr = np.array(A_corr).T 

# now generate random indices into A_corr (the zero axis) 
indices = np.random.choice(np.arange(A_corr.shape[0]),size=2)

# for k elements, do 
# indices = np.random.choice(np.arange(A_corr.shape[0]),size=k)

# finally select the elements (3-tuples) associated with indices 
A_corr[indices]
```

Convert your tuple to an array, and then transpose it. Then generate an index array using `np.random.choice`

Comment: I'm not following the transpose?

Comment: It's exactly what you did with `[: , column]`. Personal style? :)

Comment: Transposition is a useless overhead. Just `A_corr[:,indices]`

Comment: Good. Could you change the random to have result without replacement? Because sometime result is `[[133  59 107] [133  59 107]]`

Comment: @GiuseppeMarra meh. Transposing a (50000000,3) array takes `100ns` on my machine, but sure

Answer (score 0):

Instead of randomly choosing the values from your arrays, think at the list of coordinates arrays as a unique matrix (`np.stack`). Then, what you really want is sampling k the columns of this matrix (i.e. each column contains a triple of coordinates you want to sample all together). This can be done by exploiting `np.random.choice` from the set of indices of columns (i.e. `len(A_coor[0]`).

Avoiding duplicates can be obtained by using the property `replace=False`, which has to be intended as "do not put the already sampled elements back into the elements to be sampled next".

All together:

```
import numpy as np

A_coor=np.stack((np.array([66, 67, 70, 133, 133, 133]),
            np.array([35, 35, 35, 59,  59,  59]),
            np.array([102,103,104, 105, 106, 107])), axis=0)

k=2
column = np.random.choice(len(A_coor[0]), replace=False, size=k)  

coords = A_coor[:, column]
print(coords.T)
```

Using `coords.T` allow you to have coordinates as rows, which, according to other comments, seems to be a more natural solution, but it depends on how you need to use this coordinates.

Comment: This doesn't give a 3D coordinate when run. It's not what the OP asked for.

Comment: That's because it needs to be transposed lol. This is the best solution though. `coords = coords.T`. Thanks @Giuseppe, wasn't aware of the `replace` flag

Comment: replace=False or replace=True. I meat position is not duplicated

Comment: `replace=False` is "not duplicate". You have to read the replacement like "should i put the sampled number again with the others when i make the next sampling?"

Comment: @kevinkayaks Yes, you could transpose the sliced matrix in the and if you want coordinates in the first axis, which is probably more natural

Comment: But the base solution that this answer prints doesn't match what the OP asked for.

Comment: Ok, that's ok! But the question didn't specify how to format multiple coordinates, and I think it was not the point of the question. Their doubt was about how to pick two different random indices and slicing correspondently on the original tensor, which, indeed, has coordinates as columns.

Comment: But they did. "the output should be `(67,35,103)`" which is a vertical slice through the array. This answer opens with "All answers still don't get the final solution" and yet this is the only answer that doesn't give the requested output.